# How to fix 'YoutubePlayer stuck on landscapeMode after encountering network error'

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, youtubeplayer

I have implemented YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener and when playing in landscape mode and if error comes due to network or anything else, I want to exit landscape mode.

For this I use: `youTubePlayer?.setFullscreen(false)`

But, youtube does not exits the fullscreen mode even on call of this.
And it is stuck with error screen. 'Tap to retry' doesn't work as well.

Screenshot for reference.

https://ibb.co/NKvLFG5

Comment: are you using separate activity for full screen ?

Comment: Using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment in an activity

Comment: call onBackPress method while getting any network error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change orientation back to portrait, with setting fullscreen to false.

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```